# MongoDB aggregate on Nested data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have nested data as below,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a30ee450889c5f0ebc21116"),
"academicyear" : "2017-18",
"fid" : "be02",
"fname" : "ABC",
"fdept" : "Comp",
"degree" : "BE",
"class" : "1",
"sem" : "8",
"dept" : "Comp",
"section" : "Theory",
"subname" : "BDA",
"fbValueList" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a30eecd3e3457056c93f7af"),
        "score" : 20,
        "rating" : "Fair"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a30eefd3e3457056c93f7b0"),
        "score" : 10,
        "rating" : "Fair"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a337e53341bf419040865c4"),
        "score" : 88,
        "rating" : "Excellent"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a337ee2341bf419040865c7"),
        "score" : 75,
        "rating" : "Very Good"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a3380b583dde50ddcea350e"),
        "score" : 72,
        "rating" : "Very Good"
    }
]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3764f1bc19b77dd9fd9a57"),
    "academicyear" : "2017-18",
    "fid" : "be02",
    "fname" : "ABC",
    "fdept" : "Comp",
    "degree" : "BE",
    "class" : "1",
    "sem" : "5",
    "dept" : "Comp",
    "section" : "Theory",
    "subname" : "BDA",
    "fbValueList" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a3764f1bc19b77dd9fd9a59"),
            "score" : 88,
            "rating" : "Excellent"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a37667aee64bce1b14747d2"),
            "score" : 74,
            "rating" : "Good"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a3766b3ee64bce1b14747dc"),
            "score" : 74,
            "rating" : "Good"
        }
    ]
}
```

We are trying to perform aggregation using this,

```
db.fbresults.aggregate([{$match:{academicyear:"2017-18",fdept:'Comp'}},{$group:{_id: {fname: "$fname", rating:"$fbValueList.rating"},count: {"$sum":1}}}])
```

and we get result like,

```
{ "_id" : { "fname" : "ABC", "rating" : [ "Fair","Fair","Excellent","Very Good", "Very Good",  "Excellent", "Good", "Good" ] }, "count" : 2 }
```

but we are expecting result like,

```
{ "_id" : { "fname" : "ABC", "rating_group" : [ 
        { 
            rating: "Excellent"
            count: 2 
        },
            { 
            rating: "Very Good"
            count: 2 
        },
            { 
            rating: "Good"
            count: 2 
        },
            { 
            rating: "Fair"
            count: 2 
        },

    ] }, "count" : 2 }
```

We want to get individual faculty group by their name and inside that group by their rating response and count of rating.

We have already tried this one but we did not the result.
[Mongodb Aggregate Nested Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456436/mongodb-aggregate-nested-group)

Comment: Which mongo version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        academicyear: "2017-18",
        fdept:'Comp'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$fbValueList" // flatten the fbValueList array into multiple documents
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            fname: "$fname",
            rating:"$fbValueList.rating"
        },
        count: {
            "$sum": 1 // this will give us the count per combination of fname and fbValueList.rating
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.fname", // we only want one bucket per fname
        rating_group: {
            $push: { // we push the exact structure you were asking for
                rating: "$_id.rating",
                count: "$count"
            }
        },
        count: {
            $avg: "$count" // this will be the average across all entries in the fname bucket
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It gives me the results that i want. thanks again. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is a long aggregation pipeline, there may be some aggregations that are un-necessary, so please check and discard whichever are irrelevant.

**NOTE:** This will only work with `Mongo 3.4+`.

You need to use `$unwind` and then `$group` and `$push` ratings with their counts.

```
matchAcademicYear = {
    $match: { 
        academicyear:"2017-18", fdept:'Comp' 
    }
}

groupByNameAndRating = {
    $group: {
        _id: { 
            fname: "$fname", rating:"$fbValueList.rating"
        },
        count: {
            "$sum":1
        }
    }
}

unwindRating = {
    $unwind: "$_id.rating"
}

addFullRating = {
    $addFields: {
        "_id.full_rating": "$count"
    }
}

replaceIdRoot = {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$_id"
    }
}


groupByRatingAndFname = {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "rating": "$rating",
            "fname": "$fname"
        },
        count: {"$sum": 1},
        full_rating: {"$first": "$full_rating"}
    }
}

addFullRatingAndCount = {
    $addFields: {
        "_id.count": "$count",
        "_id.full_rating": "$full_count"
    }
}

groupByFname = {
    $group: {
        _id: "$fname",
        rating_group: { $push: {rating: "$rating", count: "$count"}},
        count: { $first: "$full_rating"}
    }    
}

db.fbresults.aggregate([
    matchAcademicYear, 
    groupByNameAndRating, 
    unwindRating, 
    addFullRating, 
    unwindRating, 
    replaceIdRoot, 
    groupByRatingAndFname, 
    addFullRatingAndCount, 
    replaceIdRoot, 
    groupByFname
])
```